# Creating subdomains on apache2 server with dynamic IP

Tags: apache, ubuntu, subdomain, httpd.conf, dynamic-ip

So basically I'm having issues creating a subdomain on my server. I'm running apache2 on a Ubuntu 12.04 server and have dynamic IP set up with No-IP.com.

I have mydomain.com working, but want to create test.mydomain.com directing towards a subfolder in my /var/www/ directory (where everything for my website is located).

I modified the code on [apache vhosts examples page](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html) and put this in my httpd.conf file:

```
# Ensure that Apache listens on port 80
Listen 80

# Listen for virtual host requests on all IP addresses
NameVirtualHost localhost:80

<VirtualHost localhost:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/
ServerName mydomain.com

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost localhost:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/test
ServerName test.mydomain.com

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>
```

When I try and restart the service:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

 * Restarting web server apache2                                                                                                                                                                            apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Please let me know if I'm forgetting to include any necessary information.

*Update*
I tried using *:80 but I still got an error, that's why I switched to localhost.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                                                                                                                                            apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
[Thu Nov 21 15:03:51 2013] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
[Thu Nov 21 15:03:51 2013] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

**UPDATE** I figured out what was going on. I had a matching configuration entry in my ports.conf file. Once I removed that, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your apache conf seems correct if you replace localhost with *. That means that you should use `NameVirtualHost *:80` and `<VirtualHost *:80>`

However, you must tell the DNS server to forward subdomains to your dynamic IP. Since you have a .com domain from a paid DNS service, you must login to your DNS provider and setup A records or CNAME records to your IP (add the same settings you have in your main .com domain). If you use the a ddclient or similar client to automatically update the domains, you can configure it to update the subdomain as well.

In any case, use command `nslookup yourdomain.com` and `nslookup subdomain.domain.com` to see if the subdomain is updated successfully. Note that updates in DNS may take hours before they are actually in effect.

**EDIT:**

Sorry just noticed : `(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80`.  This means that somebody else is already using port 80, so the apache server cannot bind to that address. Use `sudo netstat -anltp | grep :80` to see which program has bound port 80. Also, check your conf files to make sure that you have no more `NameVirtualHost *:80` directives.

Last, `apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName` is not an error, it's just a warning so you shouldn't be worried about this

Comment: I tried using *:80 but I still got an error, that's why I switched to localhost.

Comment: Apache....
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16644/apache2

Comment: So apache works? Try using `sudo apache2ctl restart` instead of `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Answer (score 0):

Possible that there a service using port :80
Try  `netstat -tulpn |grep :80` on command line to see which service is occupying this port. In my case, it was nginx. I stopped the service then started the one I wanted to use (apache2).